# How to hide mouse cursor completely for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I am using iMX6 board with touch screen. And Ubuntu 12.04 OS was running on it.
Since it is a touch screen, I don't want any mouse connected to it. So, I want the mouse cursor to hide completely.

I had tried unclutter. But when I am touching the screen the cursor becomes visible. I want the cursor to be hidden completely.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide the mouse cursor](http://askubuntu.com/questions/157134/how-to-hide-the-mouse-cursor)

Comment: In that they had mentioned like use : 
startx -nocursor

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use [a blank cursor theme](http://superuser.com/questions/158938/hide-mouse-cursor-in-ubuntu-for-touchscreen) instead

Comment: I had tried that its not working :(

Comment: "startx -nocursor" worked. Thank You