# Hide the mouse cursor while viewing a Amazon movie

Tags: 20.04, mouse, video, ubuntu-mate

Is there a way to hide the mouse cursor while viewing an Amazon movie?

Without disabling it when I stop viewing the movie.

I also frequently have to adjust my volume which does require my mouse.

A quandry indeed. :-)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/a/157426/1746598 its about unclutter, an app that can hide you mouse after inactivity.

This command will hide the mouse instantly

```
unclutter -idle 0.01 -root
```

You can probably map it to a keyboard shortcut so you can enable and disable

Or use this command

```
unclutter -idle 10 -root
```

to hide after 10 seconds of inactivity

Answer (score -1):

For me it normally works to move the mouse cursor into the lower right corner or some other edge of the display.

If you can still see it, look if increasing the mouse pointer size does help (as contradictory as this may read, but I found it to add more space around it).

If you have any of the other mouse pointer usability options enabled, like the crosshairs, this technique naturally does not apply.